# cakephp - Unable to retrieve session in controller

Tags: php, session, cakephp, scope

I am having problems with cakephp session. I created a session in my controller (users/home) then I attempted to retrieve it in another controller, but I wasn't able to get it.

Also, I created another session in another controller and was unable to retrieve it in the users controller.

I would like to know how to stop this behaviour.

Thanks

Note: I use the session component.

Comment: can you show us some code? wire-frame? debug message? var_dump of session?

Comment: did you put the session component in the app_controller so it would be on all controllers? show us how you do the calls. Also check in the config/core.php if you have the auto start session variable set to true

Comment: Thanks, solved it. A proxy software was the cause. Turned it off and everything just works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `$components = array('Session');` (and any other app wide components) in your AppController.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1311/Methods